# Variance of $\tanh z$ where $z\sim{\cal N}(0,\sigma^2)$

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, hyperbolic-functions, neural-networks

In Priors for Infinite Networks [(Neal, 1996)](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eradford/ftp/pin.ps), the paper considers a simple one hidden layer neural network defined by \begin{align}h &= \tanh (a + Ux) \\
f &= b + Vh\end{align} where $f(x)$ is the output.

I'm interested in the term $V(x) = \Bbb E[h_j(x)^2]$. In the paper it only says it's finite so that the CLT can be applied. Suppose $x$ is a fixed input and $a, U$ are defined as i.i.d. normally distributed weights, so that $z=a + Ux$ is normally distributed with zero mean. Then the question becomes: what is the variance of $\tanh z= \operatorname{E}[\tanh^2 z]$?

Maybe there's a nice integration trick using trig identities?

Related question: [Integral (Tanh and Normal)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1763428/integral-tanh-and-normal/4131574)

Comment: [WA says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28tanh+z%29%5E2*exp%28-z%5E2%2F2%29%2Fsqrt%282*pi%29+from+-inf+to+inf&dataset=) it's $0.394294$. It doesn't obtain a closed form, but for neural network purposes a few decimal places will likely be enough.

Comment: The paper is all theory about "infinitely wide" neural networks anyway, so the numbers are not important for computation, just theory.

Comment: If all you want is a proof the variance is finite, use $-1<\tanh z<1\implies0\le\tanh^2z<1$ (you already used the antecedent in proving $E[\tanh z]$ is $0$ rather than being undefined).

Comment: Oh I know that, it's explained in the paper. I wonder what the exact form is though.

Comment: I specified z as 0 mean so tanh z has mean 0 also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z\sim{\cal N}(0,\sigma^2)$. We wish to evaluate $$\Bbb E[\tanh^2z]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-z^2/2\sigma^2}}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\tanh^2z\,dz=\frac1\sigma\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-z^2/2\sigma^2}\tanh^2z\,dz.$$ Integrate by parts to get \begin{align}\int_0^\infty e^{-z^2/2\sigma^2}\tanh^2z\,dz&=\left.e^{-z^2/2\sigma^2}(z-\tanh z)\right\vert_0^\infty+\frac1{\sigma^2}\int_0^\infty ze^{-z^2/2\sigma^2}(z-\tanh z)\,dz\\&=\frac1{\sigma^2}\left(\int_0^\infty z^2e^{-z^2/2\sigma^2}\,dz-\int_0^\infty ze^{-z^2/2\sigma^2}\tanh z\,dz\right).\end{align} The first integral is a classic and is equal to $\sigma^3\sqrt{\pi/2}$. For the second integral, let $u=z^2$ so \begin{align}\int_0^\infty ze^{-z^2/2\sigma^2}\tanh z\,dz&=\frac12\int_0^\infty e^{-u/2\sigma^2}\tanh\sqrt u\,du.\end{align} This is the Laplace transform of $\tanh\sqrt u$ which has [no elementary closed form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplace+transform+tanh%28sqrt%28t%29%29). So at most, we can write \begin{align}\Bbb E[\tanh^2z]&=1-\frac1{\sigma^3\sqrt{2\pi}}{\cal L}\left[\tanh\sqrt t\right](1/2\sigma^2)=1-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(f(n+1)-f(n))\end{align} where $f(x)=xe^{2\sigma^2x^2}\operatorname{erfc}(\sigma x\sqrt2)$.

Comment: I'm not good at integrals but this looks reasonable. Is there a nicer form for $\sigma = 1$?

Comment: @qwr No because we still need to evaluate the Laplace transform which is the problematic part. It is possible to obtain closed forms in the limiting cases $\sigma\to0,\infty$ though.

Comment: Just wondering, is the "classic" first integral just the scaled integral for variance of a Gaussian?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$