# Fixed points of $\mathbb{E} \tanh(ax+bg)$ where $g$ is $N(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to compute the number of fixed points of the following function:

$$ f(x) = \mathbb{E} \tanh(ax+bg) $$

Where $a,b >0$ and $g$ is $N(0,1)$.

So far I have managed to show that when $a \leq 1$ there is a unique fixed point at $x=0$, and now I am interested in the case $a>1$.  Computer simulations seem to indicate that there are at most $3$ fixed points (at least for integer $a<500$).

I have also tried directly computing this functions power series representation following the posted solution in this thread : [Integral (Tanh and Normal)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1763428/integral-tanh-and-normal)
but the coefficients themselves aren't very tractable for direct computations.

Any help or ideas is appreciated!

Comment: At least, I can confirm the situation for $a>1$ via simulations too. Interesting problem, where did this come from by the way, is there any more context? I will try to tackle it using series, or something else in the meantime...

Comment: For context the fixed points of this equation arise as the minimizing function for the free energy of the mean field random field ising model. The paper "Fluctuations in the Curie-Weiss version of the Random Field Ising model" by Amaro de Matos and Fernando Perez show this result.